# Xamarin.iOS: MobileService.InvokeApiAsync skips

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am developing an app using Xamarin.Forms to re-use as much code as possible.
Specifically, I have a static class that manages all the POST/GET requests to my Azure Web Server.
Everything single call works fantastically except for one call - this one:

```
public async static Task<Models.UserParkPosition> GetUserParkPositionForCurrentUserAsync()
{
    var body = new JArray { App.User.Id };

    var test = await AzureMobileServiceClient.Instance.MobileService.InvokeApiAsync<JArray, Models.UserParkPosition>(ConnectionsAPI, body, HttpMethod.Get, null);
    return test;
}
```

The method above is called when the user presses a button - specifically like this:

```
private async Task OnGoingToTheParkClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool success = false;
    var already = await viewModel.AlreadyHavePendingRequestAsync());
    Console.WriteLine("TEST");
    throw new Exception();
}
```

When the debugger hits the "var test" line mentioned, above.... nothing happens. The code doesn't deadlock, the UI is still responsive, but the code never returns. I never see the "TEST" word and the exception is not even thrown... what happens?? 
All my other APIs are called in the same way, and are working correctly.

OTHER INFO:
- Same code works on UWP and Android
- The GET request arrives at the webservice, which responds in a timely fashion (< 1 sec)

Thanks to anyone who might help or even point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue - InvokeApiAsync throws an exception which is not catched anywhere from any calling thread. It somehow just disappears without causing any error nor device log, nor crash. Weird, but that's how the world goes.